# Errors while trying to use pip on OpenShift

Tags: pip, openshift

I am getting the following error both when using git and when logging in via rhc and try to install the requirements file:

```
The directory '/var/lib/openshift/***/.cache/pip/http' or its parent 
directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. 
Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. 
If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I am not trying to install with `sudo`.
What I am trying to do is:

1. Log into via rhc and and ssh: rhc ssh 'app'
2. activate venv: `source $OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR/virtenv/bin/activate`
3. `pip install -r "$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR" requirements.txt`

Note that `$OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR` and `$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR` are the environment variables given by OpenShift to access the relevant folders.

Any ideas? I am on a Python 2.7 cartridge.

Comment: define in the question OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR and OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR

Comment: @Dombi-Szabolcs: edited.

Comment: I'm getting the same error on a fresh python-2.7 cartridge.

Answer (score 0):

Openshift will automatically install your dependencies based on a `requirements.txt` file. So you shouldn't ssh into your app and do that yourself.

You can find more information about it on the developer center pages. [[1]](https://developers.openshift.com/languages/python/deployment-options.html)